# Как привести в рабочее состояние всплывающее окно?

Tags: ajax, javascript, css

Вот такой у меня скрипт, мне нужно что вот этот код приводился в действие после успешной операции скрипта Ajax.

```
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Ваши данные изменены!
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Скрыть PopUp при загрузке страницы    
        PopUpHide();
    });
    //Функция отображения PopUp
    function PopUpShow(){
        $("#popup1").show();
    }
    //Функция скрытия PopUp
    function PopUpHide(){
        $("#popup1").hide();
 }
     </script>

<script>
       $('#osForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "save_edit.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#osForm').serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        //обработка успешной отправки
PopUpShow();
      },
      error: function(response) {
        //обработка ошибок при отправке
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Все теперь работает!

Comment: @lifting, а что вы пытались сделать сами? Какой именно момент вам не понятен?

Comment: Уже все работает =)